# MySQL: how to sort by tags (quantity of tags then priority of tags)

Tags: mysql

Given three tables (articles, articleTags, tags)...

Typically, "related articles by tag" are ranked based on HOW MANY of the original article’s tags they match. So if the original article has tags of TagA, TagB, and TagC, any related articles that also have all three tags will show up first, and trickle down based on quantity of tags matched, with no order after that data point.

What I would like to do is augment the behavior that occurs after the typical behavior.

If the original article has TagA at *priority* 1, TagB at *priority* 2, and TagC at *priority* 3, the order should still favor a greater quantity of matched tags, but then resort to the priorities as above: articles sharing TagA (priority 1) should appear first; articles sharing TagB should come next; articles sharing TagC should come last.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM articles a 
  JOIN (
    SELECT articleID, SUM(at.priority) total_priority
    FROM articleTags at 
      JOIN tags t ON at.tagid = t.tagID 
    WHERE t.tagName IN ('TagA','TagB','TagC')
    GROUP BY articleID
  ) q ON a.articleID = q.articleID
ORDER BY q.total_priority
```

This is what I have set up so far, but it doesn't seem to give me the results I need.

**UPDATE:**

Just to throw something up, let's say we have four articles:

- Article A (tagged TagA, TagB, TagC)
- Article B (tagged TagB, TagC)
- Article C (tagged TagC)
- Article D (tagged TagC, TagB, TagA)
- Article E (tagged TagC, TagA)

How could I store this and retrieve it so that if I searched for **TagA** and **TagB**, I would get this output, in this order:

1. Article A (because it has both)
2. Article D (because it has both)
3. Article B (because TagB is a high priority)
4. Article E (because TagA is a lower priority)

Basically, while this example is primitive, it illustrates the need to promote Article B because, in the editor's choice and priority of tags, Article B is more relevant to TagB than Article E is to Tag A.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: `ORDER BY q.total_priority, t.tagName` or if you want to control it based on name... use conditional order by to assign a desired priority `case when t.tagName = 'TagA' then 1 when t.tagName = 'TagB' then 2 when t.tagName = 'TagC' then 3 else 4 end`  you could avoid the hard-coding if the priority was stored with the tags table.  but I'm sure I don't understand the whole question here.

Comment: The priority per article will be different. One article may be more about TagB than about TagA, so TagB will have 1st place, whereas TagA will have 2nd place—hence the storage in the articleTags table. Does that help?

Comment: Sounds intriguing; but I'm just not following: with  mocked up data and expected results I would probably get there.

Comment: I've updated the question to include an example.

Comment: ok, I'm there almost... so order of the inputs matter?, because Article D, like Article A has both has both tags B and A. I would have thought the order would be D, A, B, E.  but that's not the case... so order of tags seems to matter.

Comment: Yes, the order of the tags = priority. If there's a smart way to write this out in SQL, I'm all ears. All I've seen in typical tag joins is the "quantity" of tags that match generating the order of the results. But I wanted to go that extra step.